# Making Product Out of Stock in Hybris through HMC

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to show product out of stock manually using hybris through HMC.Is there any way through which we can make it out of stock?Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow these steps to make a product out of stock via hMC.

1. Go to hMC->Catalogs->Products and open the desired product.
2. Under the "Stock" tab, click on "Find stocks levels for this product".
3. Now you will have a list of warehouses in which the product is available in stock.
4. Right click on the warehouse in which you want to make to product out of stock and click "Edit in new window".
5. Now either change the value of the variable "Available amount" to zero or change the "In stock status" to 'forceOutOfStock'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a hybris fresher. Regarding this idea , what I have seen in my project and several other products is,
Go to hMC->Catalogs->Products and open the desired product... under the "Extended attributes" menu , I am able to see an attribute namely , EAN (could vary) which holds either "Y/N". when made to Y, it changes the product to outofstock. I dont know if this could be of any help, but just wanted to extend the answer. Thanks